How to store data on mass storage with the shortest possible header?
I would like to save one text file on a limited memory mass storage (~22kB). The problem is that the file system header size is too big for this application. The standard FAT32 header takes ~20kB of memory. In case of FAT12 it is only ~10kB, but that is too much for my application, I need to reduce the header size as much as possible because I need more space for the data stored in the file.
I would like to ask if there is any file system that requires less space for the header, or is it possible to reduce the FATFS header size (for example, not storing date or name information)?

You could maybe try to write to unformatted raw partition?

@JO95, "too big for this application" --> what is the limit?

The main idea is that it should be possible to simply replace this file with another one and then save it without using any additional software. I'm not sure if this would be possible with raw data.

The more space the better :-). But let's say 5kB for the header would be acceptable.

If the storage will never have anything else on it except this one file, you don't need a filesystem.  Using a raw partition will suffice.

Thank you for the advices. When I put the raw data in msc and try to read it on the computer, it only allows me to format the disk (I'm working on Windows). How can I view this data or replace them with something else?
